# Make arrayList with SQlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I want to make arrayList with SQLite Database , i have packages class that initializes data

Here is the code that i currently have this includes meta data

```
Packages[] packages = {

new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal"),
new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal"),
new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal"),
new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal"),
new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal"),
new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal"),
new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal"),
new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal"),
new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal"),
new Packages("name", "price", "vol", "duration", "*sub", "*unsub", "bal")

};
```

but i want to achieve something like this, with below code i get Cursor Data so i want to use that data to initialize arrayList

```
mydb = new PackagesDbHelper(getActivity());
    Cursor result = mydb.getAllData();

    Packages[] packages = {};

    whilte (result.moveToNext()) {
    packages = new packages(result.getString(1), result.getString(2),
    result.getString(3),
    result.getString(4),
    result.getString(5),
    result.getString(6),
    result.getString(7), )
    }
```

Here is Packages class

```
public class Packages {

String packageName, packagePrice, packageVol, packageDuration, packageSub, packageUnsub, packageBal;

public Packages(String name, String price, String vol, String duration, String sub, String unsub, String bal) {
    this.packageName = name;
    this.packagePrice = price;
    this.packageVol = vol;
    this.packageDuration = duration;
    this.packageSub = sub;
    this.packageUnsub = unsub;
    this.packageBal = bal;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to add the results of your query to an ArrayList. You just need to add a few lines to your existing code:

```
// This list will be populated with the query results:
ArrayList<Packages> packageList = new ArrayList<Packages>();

while (result.moveToNext()) {
     final Packages package = new Packages(result.getString(1), 
          result.getString(2),
          result.getString(3),
          result.getString(4),
          result.getString(5),
          result.getString(6),
          result.getString(7));
}

packageList.add(package);
```

Comment: i get this error "add (packages) in ArrayList cannot be applied to (Packages[])